# Not able to read the dom content in puppeteer [node.js] using class & objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, webautomation

I'm trying to read the dom content from [indian superleague](https://indiansuperleague.com) for example goals, attacking, mins per goal, etc using class and object. It gives an error like this

Evaluation failed: TypeError: **Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined**
    at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:7:64
    
Here's the code

config.js

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

class Puppeteer{
    constructor(){
        this.param = {
            path: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
            url: 'https://indiansuperleague.com',
        }   
    }

    async connect(){
        this.param.browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: this.param.path, headless: false})
        this.param.page = await this.param.browser.newPage()
        await this.param.page.goto(this.param.url, {timeout: 0})
    }

    async disconnect(){
        await this.param.browser.close()
    }
}

module.exports = Puppeteer
```

states.js

```js
class States{
    constructor(param){
        this.param = param
    }

    async fetchData(){
        const page = this.param.page

        const res = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const title = 'si-fkt-sctn-title', value = 'si-fkt-sctn-number'
            // const titleArray = document.getElementsByClassName(title)
            // const valueArray = document.getElementsByClassName(value)

            let key = document.getElementsByClassName(title)[0].textContent.trim()
            let num = document.getElementsByClassName(value)[0].textContent.trim()

            /* for(let i=0; i<titleArray.length; i++){
                key[i] = titleArray[i].textContent.trim()
                num[i] = valueArray[i].textContent.trim()
                // Object.defineProperty(temp, key, {value:num,writable: true,configurable: true,enumerable: true})
            } */

            return {key, num}
        })

        console.log(res)
    }

}

module.exports = States
```

app.js

```js
const Puppeteer = require('./config')
const States = require('./modules/states')

const puppeteer = new Puppeteer()
const states = new States(puppeteer.param)

puppeteer.connect().then(async() => {    
    let res = await states.fetchData()
    console.log(res)
    
    await puppeteer.disconnect()
}).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The elements may be created dynamically after some time. You can try to use `page.waitForSelector()` before retrieving the data from them. For example:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://indiansuperleague.com');

    await Promise.all([
      page.waitForSelector('.si-fkt-sctn-title'),
      page.waitForSelector('.si-fkt-sctn-number'),
    ]);

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return [
        document.querySelector('.si-fkt-sctn-title').textContent,
        document.querySelector('.si-fkt-sctn-number').textContent,
      ];
    });

    console.log(data);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Output:

```
[ ' Goals', ' 63' ]
```